# PHP List All Combination of Elements of Array

Tags: php, arrays, process, combinations

I have an array:

```
$arr=array("A","B","C");
```

I want to make its all of combination as:

```
array("A")
array("B")
array("C")
array("A","B")
array("A","C")
array("B","C")
array("A","B","C")
```

i want to make an process all of this combinations but i don't want generate all combinations, store them in an array and apply function to them. Because this requires a lot of memory with large combinations. I have 40 items for this process (I have long time but i don't have enough memory).

I want to have a function like this:

```
function ProcessArrayCombinations($array){
foreach($array as $v){
//generate and process next combination of array
print_r($nextcombination);
}
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code recognizes the combinations as binary numbers, using the fact that there is a [formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination#Number_of_k-combinations_for_all_k) which states that the sum of all combinations possible from n elements is 2^n. Knowing its binary logarithm is integer, we can define a model where each possible binary number constructed from n digits is a set of combinations. Code is untested, if there are typos, please, let me know in comments.

```
function ProcessArrayCombinations($array) {
    $status = array();
    foreach ($array as $element) {
        $status[] = false;
    }

    $elementCount = count($status);
    $trues = 0;

    while ($trues < $elementCount) {
        $index = 0;
        $stop = false;
        while ((!$stop) && ($index < count($status)) && ($status[$index])) {
            $status[$index] = false;
            $trues--;
            $index++;
        }
        $status[$index] = true;
        $trues++;
        //Found a new combination
        //We should print elements from $array located at indexes fulfilling
        //the criteria that the element having the same index in $status is true:
        //for ($i = 0; $i < count($status); $i++) {
        //    if ($status[$i}) {
        //        print
        //    } else {
        //        don't print
        //    }
        //}
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your reply but i don't understand how can i print founded combinations :/

Comment: i found it; thank you. this solved my request. but you may change $status.length to count($status) i++ to $i++ and $status.length to count($status) again.

Comment: True, the code was untested. I have added the fixes proposed by you.

Comment: you may change $elementCount = $status.length; too.

Comment: and so; i have a new question: can i set starting element to another?

Comment: It is incompatible with the end sign, but you can set an offset for your display using formulas of modulo theory.

Answer (score 0):

I edited and used your function as below. Thank you again Lajos.

```
function ProcessArrayCombinations($array) {
    $status = array();
    foreach ($array as $element) {
        $status[] = false;
    }

    $elementCount = count($status);
    $trues = 0;

    while ($trues < $elementCount) {
        $index = 0;
        $stop = false;
        while ((!$stop) && ($index < count($status)) && ($status[$index])) {
            $status[$index] = false;
            $trues--;
            $index++;
        }
        $status[$index] = true;
        $trues++;
        //Found a new combination
        //We should print elements from $array located at indexes fulfilling
        //the criteria that the element having the same index in $status is true:
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($status); $i++) {
            if ($status[$i]) {
                echo $array[$i];
            }
        }
echo '<br/>';
    }
}
```